# Specific sum of a root of $x^{2017} - 2x + 1$

Tags: polynomials

If we let $x$ be a root of $x^{2017} - 2x + 1$ such that $x \neq 1,$ than find the value of $$\sum_{k=0}^{2016} x^{k}.$$

I tried to calculate a root of $x^{2017} - 2x + 1$ that wasn't $1$ using WA, which failed. I than tried to find a relationship between the sum and $x^{2017} - 2x + 1,$ and that also failed. Can someone give me a nudge in the right direction?

Comment: Try to multiply the sum by $(x-1)$, it might give you some idea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a nudge, as requested:

Don't try to find $x$. Instead, consider evaluating that sum **in terms of $x$**. In particular, do you know the formula for the sum of a geometric series?

Comment: Hmm, I believe I do. However, how should I use that?

Comment: You shouldn't. You should wait until someone else gives you a complete solution rather than the nudge you requested, and then accept that answer. :(

Comment: I wasn;t really saying you should accept my answer; I was bemoaning the state of MSE.

Comment: I still think your answer deserves an acception. This answered what I wanted, which was a nudge, which I got, but the other person gave a full solution, which isn't what I wanted, and an acception is for an answer that solves my problem.

Answer (score 6):

We know that
$$(x-1) \left(\sum _{k=0}^{2016} x^k\right)=x^{2017}-1$$
from the equation is given that
$$x^{2017}-1=2 x-2$$
Therefore we have
$$\sum _{k=0}^{2016} x^k=\frac{x^{2017}-1}{x-1}=\frac{2x-2}{x-1}=2$$
Answer is $$\sum _{k=0}^{2016} x^k=2$$

Answer (score 3):

**Hints:**

$\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}ar^{i}=\frac{a(1-r^{n})}{1-r}$ for $r\neq 1$ (sum of the first n terms of a [geometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#:%7E:text=In%20mathematics%2C%20a%20geometric%20series,previous%20term%20by%201%2F2.)) and if $x$ is a root of $x^{2017}-2x+1$, then it satisfies $x^{2017}-2x+1=0$.